# capping VM IO with cgroups

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, cgroup

I'm using cgroups to cap disk IO that a VM does by using libvirt's support for cgroups.

So, I'm getting the major/minor number of the device from a 'ls -lL' on the drive where the '.img' file for the VM is located.

However, when I try to cap the IO, I get an error - 
`root@Silver:/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/sysdefault/libvirt/qemu/debian1# echo "8:6 1048576" > blkio.throttle.read_bps_device 
bash: echo: write error: No such device`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be mixing sysctl syntax and filesystem syntax for these options.  Check what the actual path is to the sysfs file you are wanting to write to (is it `/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/sysdefault/libvirt/qemu/debian1/blkio/throttle/read_bps_device`?).

Comment: no, the path seems right. There are no subfolders in 'debian1'..

Comment: Yeah, but is there a file `blkio.throttle.read_bps_device` in that folder?  All the files in `/sys/` that can be there are already there; you cannot create them normally.  Therefore it's likely that you have the wrong path.  Alternatively, you need a kernel module you've not built, or you are doing it from the host when you should be doing it from the VM or visa versa.

Comment: yes, there is a `blkio.throttle.read_bps_device` and I am writing it correctly. In fact, there another CentOS machine at school where it works fine for me, but this does not work on my Kubuntu system. So i think I must be missing a configuration setting somewhere, dont know what..

Comment: Try doing `stat` on that file.  It's possible you may be missing a kernel module for it...

Comment: stat does not show any errors -  `stat blkio.throttle.read_bps_device 
  File: blkio.throttle.read_bps_device
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 13206       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2012-05-03 09:55:23.762720263 -0400
Modify: 2012-05-03 09:55:23.762720263 -0400
Change: 2012-05-03 09:55:23.762720263 -0400
 Birth: -`

Comment: It's the `Device: 19h/25d` part that is important.  Getting errors when you tried to stat this type of file would be really weird.  Usually the device is 0/0 for sysfs files, but yours may be different.  Check that it is the same as on the working system.  If it is, this is most likely a kernel bug.  If it is not, check that you have an item in `mount` like this: `sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)`.